# How to download the audio files on Wikipedia pages?

Tags: wikipedia, download, audio

Sometimes a Wikipedia page contains audio files that I would like to download and save, for example, the individual pronunciations in the [IPA chart for consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio). However, I wasn't able to find any explicit audio file to download. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to these pages:

- [Vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio)
- [Consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_consonant_chart_with_audio)

And then right click on the speaker icon next to the sound you would like to download, and press "Open link in new tab". Then you you can right click the audio player shown in the new tab, and click "Save audio as..."

Answer (score 1):

I think the ones you want are sourced from http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/introducing_the_ipa/ and there are .mp3 files there that are downloadable.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the audio play button using your browser's dev tools, you can see an `img` nearby in the structure, like so:

```
<div class="mwPlayerContainer k-player">
    <div class="videoHolder"><div class="mwEmbedPlayer" id="mwe_player_0">
        <img src="data:image/png,blahblah" class="playerPoster"> <!-- This is the element that changes -->
    </div>
    <div title="Play clip" class="play-btn-large"></div>
</div>
```

When the play button is clicked, the `img` is changed to an `audio` element, which is then played. If you click play then double click on the `audio` element's `src` before it goes away, you can get the audio file source, such as [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bilabial_nasal.ogg). Just replace `file///` with `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons`.

But an easier way in cases where it's possible is to view the original source, [as pnuts suggests](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106660/140514).

Comment: Thanks, tried inspecting elements but didn't expect the element to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This how I did it, it's a bit complicated but it worked.
Take [this IPA letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel) as an example -

You first have to click the **source** button under the audio player.
That in turn makes you go to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Close_front_unrounded_vowel.ogg)

After that, you will click on the **`Menu`** option on the audio player.

Then you click on the download button and select the **MP3** option. That will get you to [this page](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/9/91/Close_front_unrounded_vowel.ogg/Close_front_unrounded_vowel.ogg.mp3).

You then click on the `right icon` to **Download**, change the ".ogg" to a ".mp3", save and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

just follow visuals and you will get there...
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vuhZ.png**
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVtYG.gif**

[image]
[image]